# How to do custom dialog validation for text field length in classic ui in cq5

Tags: aem

I want to display message in popup like "Please enter 10 characters only" if text field exceeds the required length in classic ui dialog text field while submitting.

I have reffered the following link:

- [AEM Touch UI Dialog Validation](http://adobeaemclub.com/aem-touch-ui-dialog-validation/)
- [Form field Validation – Classic UI Dialog](http://adobeaemclub.com/form-field-validation-classic-ui-dialog/)

My requirement is like first link but this is in touch UI. I need the same in classic UI Dialog.I tried but i am not getting.

Please suggest me to get this requirement.

Thanks!!!

Vasantha Koppula.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you include the dialog code in your question? What went wrong?

Comment: Hi,thank you for your response... I tried with touch UI sample code(AEM Touch UI Dialog Validation), at that time i am able to validate the text field length and getting popup with error message. But in case of classic UI i am unable to validate. What i need to change for validation.js script.

Answer (score 0):

The Classic UI uses the ExtJs framework. You should be able to use the `maxLength` property on your widget to validate the input:

```
<field
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    fieldLabel="My Field"
    maxLength=10
    name="./text"
    xtype="textfield">
</field>
```

If you need a popup, you'll need to add a `listener` to your `textfield` widget to respond to an event (i.e. blur):

```
<field
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    fieldLabel="My Field"
    name="./text"
    xtype="textfield">
    <listeners
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        blur="function(comp){
            if(comp.getValue().length > 10) {
                alert('Please enter 10 characters only');
            }
        }"/>
</field>
```

Documentation:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Dialog